# daterangepicker : dropdown menu displayed on page load

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

I am using daterangepicker inside a Salesforce Community component : I am simply loading and creating it after DOM initialization. Even though the API works great, what seems to be a bug makes its dropdown menu pop inside my page everytime it is loaded, and I have to click the `<input>` to make it act as expected. 
Here is my code : what did I do wrong ?

**HTML**

```
<div id='dateRangerContainer'>
    <input id='DRP'/>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// @brief
//  Initializes the date range picker
// @note
//  JQuery is required boi
initDateRangePicker : function( ) 
{
    var helper = this;

    $('#DRP').daterangepicker(
    {
        locale: {
            format: "DD/MM/YYYY"
        },

        autoApply: true,
        alwaysShowCalendars: true,
        parentEl: "#dateRangeContainer",
        startDate: moment().subtract(1, 'day'),
        endDate: moment(),

        ranges:{
            'Dernières 24h': [moment().subtract(1, 'day'), moment()],
            'Semaine en cours': [moment().startOf('week'), moment()],
            'Mois en cours': [moment().startOf('month'), moment()],
            'Trimestre en cours': [moment().startOf('quarter'), moment()]
        }
    }, 

    // called when user selects another date range
    function(start, end, label) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, that dropdown is used only for storing values and you do not need it visible. Try to inspect element and add `display: none` attribute.

Comment: ok cool thanks, I added this simple line `document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu')[0].style.display = 'none';`

Comment: @metheM try to look if it doesn't have specific ID or class, so you'll be able to handle hiding in your .css file